# Include runtime type definitions using VSCode extension

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm working on a library that lets users run Node processes from inside another application. The library is called "max-api"; functions for sending data to the host application are exposed through a Node module and are loaded in the expected way:

```
const maxAPI = require("max-api");
```

However, the user never interacts with this module directly. Rather, when the host application launches the Node process, it intercepts the call to require, checks if the name of the module is "max-api", and provides the module if so.

This works great, the only issue is we have no way to provide type definitions for this modules. So, the user doesn't get any autocomplete or validation for functions in the "max-api" module. I was thinking of writing a VSCode extension to provide these, but I'm not 100% sure how to get started. Thanks in advance for any advice.

Answer (score 0):

You could write a TS typings file (see [Definitely Typed](https://definitelytyped.org/)). This would be installed in `node_modules/@types` and vscode will automatically pick it up to provide code completion for your module.

Comment: Thanks for the response! So we've got a d.ts file like this, but the issue is that often our users are running Node scripts from the host application, where that script isn't inside of a package. It doesn't have any module dependencies, and hence no node_modules/@types. Maybe there's some way that our users can configure VSCode, so that if we provide the d.ts file somewhere else, VSCode can find it?

Comment: Did you try the triple-slash directive to specify a path where vscode should look for the typings file?

Comment: This works! That's pretty cool. Is there some way to have VSCode include a reference to this d.ts file without our users needing to add a reference path directive to their JS files? First, they don't know where that file is, and second I really want end users to do almost nothing to get these type definitions.

Comment: Of course is that possible! Just reference the typings files in your package.json [devDependencies](https://github.com/mike-lischke/vscode-antlr4/blob/master/package.json#L504). They must be available in the DT repository for that to work.

Comment: So, this isn't quite what I was after, since again our users are working in an unorthodox environment, running naked .js files, with no node_modules or package.json or any structure at all. But, I'm starting to think that we're trying to do a bit too much, offering types without users having to do anything, and without even a package.json existing...